# Why won't my Label-control use CSS styling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, label

I'm using a CSS file for styling, and it's working properly for all of my controls except for a label on my page.  It's the only label on the page, so maybe it's a problem w/ labels in general?  I'm changing the Label.Text property several times, and the text gets updated properly every time, but it's just raw, non-styled text.

I have the following style listed in my CSS file:

```
label.myError { font-weight:bold; font-size: 25px; color:Red; font-family: Arial }
```

I have the following label control on my web page:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblError" CssClass="myError" runat="server" />
```

Then, at various points in my code-behind, I change the Text on the Label like this:

```
lblError.Text = "Please specify a " + fieldDescription + ".";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

asp.net label renders as `span` and not `label` html element. Your css specifies that the class should work with labels only

```
label.myError { font-weight:bold; font-size: 25px; color:Red; font-family: Arial }
```

you just have to change `label.myError` to `.myError` to be like

```
.myError { font-weight:bold; font-size: 25px; color:Red; font-family: Arial }
```

and isA it will work.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.Net will output your label as a span.  So the output would be:

```
<span id="lblError" class="myError">hi</span>
```

This is why you can't use label.myError